# Web API REST Client - What is the best way to (auto-)authenticate API in Website

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, autorest

I have a .Net Core MVC Website consuming .Net Core Web API Rest service. Rest client code is generated by AutoRest.

For authentication purpose, API has two endpoints:

1. `\token:` it will accept two parameters username and password, and
   return two things: `access_token`(JWT Token), and randomly generated
   `refresh_token`.
2. `\token\refresh` which will accept two parameters: `access_token` and
   `refresh_token` and return the new `access_token` and new `refresh_token`.

`access_token` lifetime is 24 hours,
`refresh_token` lifetime is 5 days

Lets move to website part. `UserController` has 5 standard action methods, `Index, Details, Create, Edit and Delete`.
On the very first request to Index route, retrieving list of all users. I am getting token by providing username and password to the API Client generated by AutoRest.

```
string access_token = GetAccessToken(username, password); // this will call API's \token endpoint and return access_token
HttpContext.Session.SetString("api_access_token", access_token); // put this token in session variable so it can be used for further requests.
var tokenCredentials = new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(access_token);
var api = new ApiServiceClient2.ApiServiceClientProxy2(BaseUri, tokenCredentials);
```

Then I can call my actual request to get users list

```
IList<ApiServiceClient.Models.AppUser> list = api.AppUser.GetAppUser();
```

Here one request is completed.

Lets move to second request (Details route), I am getting user detail for specific id, here I can retrieve token from session, and remaining part is same, create credentials object and call target action method.

```
string access_token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("api_access_token");
var tokenCredentials = new Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials(access_token);// I can put this token in session variable so it can be used for further requests.
var api = new ApiServiceClient2.ApiServiceClientProxy2(BaseUri, tokenCredentials);
ApiServiceClient.Models.AppUser obj = api.AppUser.GetAppUser1(id);
```

Similary I can write `Create, Edit and Delete` action methods, by getting token from session and passing to the API client.

Now what if my token got expired, how could the website come to know that it has to refresh the token by sending request to `\token\refresh` endpoint. Also when refresh token is get expired, then generate new token by re-sending username and password to `\token` endpoint.

So what is the best approach to call API with this authentication scheme. Should I write this logic(generate token, check for token expiry, refresh token, another check for refresh token expiry) in each action method of my controller? 
Obviously a reasonable website do not have only one controller, a website with 10-15 controllers, each has these 5 action methods, it will be very cumbersome to write this same logic in each action method.

As I mentioned I have generated the API client code using AutoRest tool. I want to use these auto-generated model classes and api client. Which makes it little more difficult to where to inject this logic.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do it is using `ServiceClientCredentials`.

When you configure your RestClient for DI/IoC container (code for it wasn't added last to the generator last time I looked), you can also inject a custom/configured `HttpClient` instance into it.

Extending the generated RestClient is rather trivial to support Dependency Injection with custom (and pooled) HttpClient for better performance and resource management (See [You're Using HttpClient Wrong](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx).

First you need to add a header to your RestClient that supports injection of `HttpClient`.

You create a new file `MyRestClient.Customizations.cs` and

```
public partial class MyRestClient
{
    public MyRestClient(IOptions<MyRestClientOptions> options, HttpClient httpClient, AutoRefreshingCredentials credentials)
        : base(httpClient, disposeHttpClient: true)
    {
        // to setup url in Startup.ConfigureServices
        BaseUri = options.Value.BaseUri;
        Credentials = credentials ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(credentials));
    }
}
```

note that it's a `partial class`. This way we can add custom methods, properties, constructors to the class w/o risk it being overridden the next time the generator runs.

In your `ConfigureServices` setup dependency injection and the `MyRestClientOptions`.

```
services.AddScoped<AutoRefreshCredentials>();
services.Config<MyRestClientOptions>(options =>
{
     options.BaseUri = new Uri("https://example.com/my/api/");
});
services.AddHttpClient<IMyRestClient, MyRestClient>()
    // Retrial policy with Poly
    .AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(p => p.WaitAndRetryAsync(4, (t) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(t)));
```

Finally add your `AutoRefreshCredentials` class

```
public class AutoRefreshingCredentials  : ServiceClientCredentials
{
    public const string AuthorizationHeader = "Authorization";

    public AutoRefreshingCredentials (HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        HttpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
    }

    public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

    public override Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // TODO: Check if token is valid and/or obtain a new one
        string token = await GetOrRefreshTokenAsync(...);
        request.Headers.Add(AuthorizationHeader, token);

        return base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Then just inject your `MyRestClient` client wherever you need it. Be aware of concurrency though which may trigger multiple sign-ups/token refreshing though.

Comment: Thanks @Tseng, this looks closer to what I need, I can implement this with some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

In one of our projects consuming an API, we check for each of your calls to the API if we get a HTTP 403 error indicating that the tokens are invalid. In that case simply try to get a new token and resubmit the request with a new valid token.

As you have pointed out, calling multiple methods (or having this try/catch/403-block) in every method feels out of place.

In our case, we are calling a REST API. We have one main execution method with a generic class constraint which tells the method to which class JSON.Net should deserialize the content from the JSON response. I'm not sure whether you can adopt our setup to your case.

An alternative would be to have a base class that has this retry-on-expired-token functionality and each method call would inherit from it.

Comment: Not sure base class works in this case, as OP says he's using an auto generated rest client (AutoRest which uses `Microsoft.Rest` nuget package for C# clients for the base functionality and base class)

Comment: Thanks @citronas, this could be alternative approach, but in my case because of auto-generated client code by AutoRest, partial client class approach looks better fit.